# why using space it return false?

Tags: bash, scripting, until-loop

I have to solve this problem.
I'm new in bash scripting.

This is my problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "In quale mese e anno è nato Albert Einstein?"
read risposta1 risposta2

shopt -s nocasematch
until [[ $risposta1 = marzo ]] || [[ $risposta2 = 1879 ]]
do
    echo "Risposta errata, riprova!"
    read risposta1 risposta2
done

echo "Risposta corretta"
```

Then if answering I type space 1879 the result is incorrect.
This exercise needs to be correct if I choose marzo or 1879.

This is the error:

[image: obnoxious image of text]

I also try to using "" but i receive the error command not found if I type for example g 47

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: You are only passing in one number, so that ends up in `risposta1`

Comment: @tripleee ok, but i need this space like risposta1. How I can do?

Comment: Your `read` command reads two words from standard input and stores the first word into `risposta1` and the second word into `risposta2`. I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please write **how** you invoke the program, **what** exactly is the input to the `read` statement, and how you want the variables to contain after the _read_.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to make `read` treat initial whitespace as significant without a drastic rewrite of the surrounding code. (In brief, you could set `IFS` to something impossible, then implement your own parser for the raw input.)

Comment: @user1934428 how can I set $numero1 can be an empty string?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  To define a variable and set it to an empty string, just write `varname=`.

Comment: @user1934428 I know my english isn't brilliant. I set two variable like $risposta and $risposta1. So if I type spacebar like risposta1 and 1879 like risposta2 I receive "the answer is uncorrect". With the script I've posted, how I can do?

Comment: This because 1879 like risposta2 is correct

Comment: I also try  until [[ $risposta1 = "marzo" ]] && [[ -n $risposta1 ]] || [[ $risposta2 = "1879" ]]
but it still doesn't work

Comment: With your script, if you enter on stdin `marzo  1879`, you get `marzo` on risposta1 and `1879` on risposta2. To test that both variables have the required value, test them with `[[ $risposta1 == marzo && $risposta2 == 1879 ]]`. Aside from this, you should get more inside in the workings of your program, if you turn on  tracing (with `set -x`).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nocasematch
until [[ "${risposta[0]}" = @(marzo|1879) || "${riposta[1]}" = @(marzo|1879) ]]; do
  echo "Risposta errata, riprova!"
  read -ra risposta
done
```

Comment: This will approve "marzo marzo" or "1879 1879" too, which probably isn't desired. Perhaps a simpler fix is to read a single variable and check if it's "marzo" or "1879" or "marzo 1879" (or, I guess, "1879 marzo" in case the user is Yoda).

Comment: Also, this uses extended globbing, which is disabled out of the box on some platforms.

Comment: @tripleee: Is it really? If I read the bash man page correctly, extended globbing is always enabled on the rhs of `[...]` and `[[....]]`.  No need to turn it on for just this purpose.

Comment: @user1934428 Depends on the Bash version. Out of the box on MacOS, that is a syntax error.

Comment: @triplee: I get what you mean. It is true that this feature was not in very old bash versions. I guess it was added to bash somewhere around version 4.x, and it is of course unfortunate that the OP did not mention, which bash version he is using. Since Apple does not seem to really support bash anymore, one would have to install there a more recent version manually.

Comment: That's probably a sensible recommendation _per se,_ but the focus here I think should be on clarifying why this will not work in various places, or perhaps ideally changing it to something which works more portably across diverse platforms. Many beginners simply copy/paste code from Stack Overflow without understanding it, and then complain when it doesn't work.